# Outlook Calendar Sync

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, calendar, outlook

I have synced a SharePoint 2010 Calendar with Outlook after a migration and no events are displayed in Outlook. The calendar connects to Outlook, but there are no SharePoint events displayed.

Answer (score 0):

When you hit F9 to send receive out of outlook do you see the connection to SharePoint?

[image]

When you clicked to add the calendar did you accept the message from SharePoint to allow the connection?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your account within Settings. Then, tap Sync Calendars. Two-way calendar export is supported for Microsoft 365, Outlook.com, and hybrid modern authentication for on-premises mailboxes.